# How do I create a drop down menu in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

When the user taps on UITextField I want it to display a drop down menu with 5 or more options. When the user selects one of the options, it has to be set as the text of the text field. Any ideas on how to create it?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467029/how-to-create-dropdown-in-xcode/18952583#18952583

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this sample[CustomDropDownList](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/iphone-development/custom-dropdown-list/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a UITableView I guess? With the 5 options inside. Then implement the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of the tableview to set the text inside the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can try try to use [UIPicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Drop down is not available in the iphone .Though there is an option of adding picker view inside the action sheet if you are making an application on iphone. and for ipad Application put a tableview inside a popovercontroller controller.