# How to create DropDown in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am a very new developer for IOS, i need help, How to create dropdown box in xcode, any one provide me example to create country list in drop down?

Comment: also refer to https://github.com/satishazad/SAMenuDropDown

Comment: @Ramz please don't post broken link

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here I found two demos for dropDown list, One is creating custom expandable `UITableViewCell` like :-

[image]

to

[image]

source code :- [DEMO](https://github.com/vicpenap/VPPDropDown/downloads)

**AND** Another is custom Drop Down list like:-

[image]

by clicking of test then open drop down list as bellow like image

[image: drop down list]

source code  with Tab Bar:-[DEMO](http://code.google.com/p/dropdowndemo/downloads/detail?name=dropdowndemo.zip&can=2&q=)

**updated source code  without Tab Bar :-**

http://www.sendspace.com/file/83qws5

Comment: second dropdown is fine but i want this example with tab. could you give me any example?

Comment: you simply add tab bar controller in your project and impliment above projects method

Comment: sorry nitin gohel, i want this example without tab, this example has already tabs.

Comment: wait i just epdate my answer without tab this example

Comment: i am a very new ipone developer, nitin Gohel could you help me to update dropdown on single view application, i dont want other files.

Comment: means i can not understand what you doing in your app can you explain more?

Comment: basically i have auto completed country box, i need to pull cities from the selected country, i have done auto completed country textbox, now i need simple dropdown in single view application, its quite difficult for me to move your current DropDown to move single view controller, could you help me?

Comment: i need your dropdown in single view application, no need other files and extra code.

Comment: Is this posible to create dropdown in single view application?

Comment: Thanks, but i am still stuck

my Main file


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


#import "AppDelegate.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

could you tell me what should i do, i replace code of your main file but its give me an errors.

Comment: If you want to build it by your self:
https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

Answer (score 4):

I beleive you shouldn't use dropdown boxes in iOS, as it's a desktop OS UI control element. You should think up something else using existing components (like PickerView), that's the words for UI consistency.

And if you need this anyway, you may create a table view, place it beneath your label and a triangular button(which causes it to appear and disappear) and populate it with values.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no native `DropDown` elements in iOS, you could make use of a `TextField` with custom background and a `UITableView` to accomplish that. Here is how to go about it.

Pseudocode

- Create a `TextField` and set it's delegate to parent controller
- Implement `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method
- Create a new `UIViewController` and implement `UITableView` in it programmatically.
- Create a custom protocol and create it's object (delegate) it.
- In `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method, load this controller and present it modally passing the required table's data source and set delegate as parent.
- in the new `tableViewController`, implement `UITableViewDelegate` and implement the didSelectRowAtIndex path method.
- Upon row selection, call the delegate with passing appropriate data.
- dismiss the modally presented controller.

Answer (score 2):

just for whom searching for small simple **swift combo box** here in 2016 year, i've tried a few of old and new (but obj-c) libs, and at last selected this:

https://github.com/sw0906/SWCombox

here is screenshot: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easy and simple way to design a drop down list is by representing it like a `UITableView` and some animation. This makes it look really like a **dropdownlist**. Here is a code I used for creating one . For this first import the < QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h > framework.

```
-(IBAction)DropDownTable:(id)sender
{
TableView.hidden = NO;
if(TableView.frame.origin.y ==203)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
    [TableView setFrame:CGRectMake(224, 204, 27, 160)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.view TableView];
}

else if (TableView.frame.origin.y == 204)
{
    [TableView setFrame:CGRectMake(224, 203, 27, 0)];
    TableView.hidden = YES;
}

[self.view addSubview:TableActivityLevel];
}
```

First make a tableview , declare its methods and make the array . Put this function on the click of a `UIButton` and youll see it work !!! Happy coding :)

Comment: BTW, the reliance on origin.y's value as a flag indicating whether dropdown is expanded seems very obscure [bad code smell]. I haven't looked closely at code, but hopefully it would not be hard to re-write it to use an explicit boolean flag to remember which state the dropdown is in.