# Drop-down list in navigation bar iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want to implement a drop-down list in the navigation bar, which contains all categories such as in this application:
[image]

I want to know what its name, and steps to implement it.
[image]

Comment: please show us what you have done until now ....

Comment: You can add a UIView for drop down which you can display just below the navigation bar.

Comment: please take a look my this answer you can just impliment as par your requestime hope its Helps you :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467029/how-to-create-dropdown-in-xcode/13467215#13467215 

You  can called if navigation bar button clickevent and also customize it appear view

Comment: @NitinGohel ok thank you I will see your demo and try it

Comment: @SharonNathaniel I have two table view controllers in my application, and I want to put this icon in my first table view, and when I press on it, a drop down menu appears

Comment: @sanjitshaw   
no I need it inside the navigation bar

Comment: I don't think you can increase height for uinavigationbar, I'm not sure about that. If you want to put the drop down view inside the uinavigationbar you need to adjust the height for uinavigationbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can try something like this also ... https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmenu

Comment: yes that is what i need, do you mean that I add button bar item (which is Click me in your example) and I do the implementation

Comment: You, and also you can take a 'UIButton' over the toolbar with the image.

Comment: I meant Yes in my previous comment. And happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place your View underneath the navigation bar but put its position to high so it isn't visible. Then when you press that button use UIViews animations to slide it down. It's that simple and there isn't any special kind of view.

Comment: can you please explain more about it, because I am new to IOS programing thank you

Comment: 1: Have you set up and app using navigation controller? 2: Are you building your UI in Interface Builder?

Comment: So do you want to make the table view slide down from underneath the navigation bar?

Comment: I want a custom array slide down from button bar item, which in this custom array I put some data

Comment: An array is a data structure not a UI element. Not sure yi can be much help here sorry.