# Create selection menu like HTML selection menu in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I what to create selection menu  but Picker View is use more space.

Can I create selection menu like selection menu in HTML.

This is Picker View : http://codewithchris.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/img/UIPickerView_add_uipickerview.jpg

And I Want to create selection like : http://www.jsftoolbox.com/images/screen_h_selectOneMenu.png

**Edit :** I found answer for my question at [How to create DropDown in xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467029/how-to-create-dropdown-in-xcode)

Comment: [UIPopover with a table view controller](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial) ?