# How to use UITableView within UITableView for drop down list in ios Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to use `UITableView` within `UITableViewCell` for drop down list in iOS Objective-C and shown in the below figure.

[image]

Comment: Please check this link. may this helps you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13467215/3515115

Answer (score 1):

You basically hide the tableView inside cell when your app loads, then animate it to show when tapped.

Here are some links for obj c Examples regarding expandable tableView (a bit old)

https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240435/Collapsable-Table-View-for-iOS

Or just use a library written by someone else and modify it to your liking

https://github.com/sakkaras/SKSTableView

If you can translate from swift, here's a good tutorial

https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/