# Display data based on dropdown menu list

Tags: ios, objective-c, drop-down-menu

I'm new in ios development,
i want to display my data based on dropdown menu,
when user click on dropdown button [there are 3 department(Ex. "one","two","three")] and select "one",now in one department some data is there,that data show in uitableview dynamically.

need help...give any example..

Comment: Please consider some tutorial like: http://www.edumobile.org/ios/a-simple-drop-down-list-for-iphone/ ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467029/how-to-create-dropdown-in-xcode

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ftfoldingtableview use this library

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested you can use third party for  [Dropmenu](https://github.com/nmattisson/DropdownMenu). Otherwise you can crate UIView and show when drop down button is pressed. Hold the data in 3 arrays. Based on the button selected load that array in tableview using tableview datasource methods

Answer (score 0):

first of all iOS do not have any dropdown native controller as an alternate you can use an uipickercontroller or can use custom made dropdown menu to show the list. Now with the dependency of the result selected on the dropdown button you can show another additional data of the department on another list in tableview.
Hope this help.